# Aws EventBridge PutEvent Limit error: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutEvents operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am getting error when using 10+ objects in Details while invoking Event Bridge from lambda function. What is the limit of objects that can be associated with Detail? When I used 10 or less than 10 it works fine.
Here is my code:

```
> mylist= []
>     for key in range(1,11):
>             detail = "{} \"bucket\": \"{}\", \"key\": \"{}\" {}".format("{", bucket, key, "}")
>         
>             entry = {
>                     'Source': 'EventBridge',
>                     'DetailType': 'My location',
>                     'Detail': detail
>                 }
>             mylist.append(entry)
>             
>         response = cw.put_events(
>             Entries=mylist
>         )
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two limits to consider when we put events into a Event Bridge:

1. (your problem) Entries must have minimum 1 item or Maximum 10 items. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEventsRequestEntry.html)
2. The total entry size must be less than 256KB. [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-putevent-size.html).